# Subsetting data using R or Python

Tags: python, r, csv

I want to subset the following data set. Specifically, I only want to retrieve 1)ID, 2)ASIN, 3) Group, 4) salesrank, and 5) categories in "csv" format. I am going to use R or Python. 
(R can't frequently read this kind of irregular data format).

The following data doesn't have usual format, so I don't know how to subset it. I have two-year
experience in R but mostly use the tool for statistical purpose. So, I am not used to dealing with this kind of data manipulation with the unusual format. If anyone can give me the answer (or clue), that would be great.
At the bottom is one set of the data consisting of "key:value". The final result should look like
this:

```
Id   ASIN     group salesrank categories
 1  0827229534 Book  396585     2
```

The original data looks like:

```
************************************************************************************************
Id:   1

ASIN: 0827229534

title: Patterns of Preaching: A Sermon Sampler

group: Book

salesrank: 396585

similar: 5  0804215715  156101074X  0687023955  0687074231  082721619X

categories: 2

|Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Preaching[12368]

|Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Sermons[12370]

reviews: total: 2  downloaded: 2  avg rating: 5

2000-7-28  cutomer: A2JW67OY8U6HHK  rating: 5  votes:  10  helpful:   9

2003-12-14  cutomer: A2VE83MZF98ITY  rating: 5  votes:   6  helpful:   5
```

Comment: How are you getting / reading the data into R?

Comment: Sorry, that's another problem. R can't read the data set properly. I might try to use Python as well. Can you give me some clue assuming that I will be using python if you can?

Comment: Is it text? You will need to get familiar with regular expressions. Build up a list of the desired elements using `grep` and `strsplit` then convert to a data.frame after.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I think I should. But, now I have only little time to do the job, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Emily I reformatted your input data; could you check if this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try in `R` by

1. Reading the file using `readLines`
2. Create a pattern with `paste` to `subset` the lines using `grep`
3. `split` the "lines1" into a `list` with list elements being each of the `prefix` groups.  Before the `split`, I removed the `LHS` and `RHS` of `:` using `sub`.
4. `cbind` the list elements using `do.call(cbind` and convert it to a `data.frame`
5. This will return columns of class `character`.  It is not clear which one should be `character/numeric`

NOTE: I created two records just to reproduce the problem.

```
     lines <- readLines('file.txt')
     pat <- paste0(c('Id', 'ASIN', 'group', 'salesrank', 'categories'),
                                        ':', collapse='|')
     lines1 <- lines[grep(pat, lines)]
     val <- str_trim(sub(".*:", "", lines1))
     Grp <- sub(":.*", '', lines1)

     library(stringr)
     res <- do.call(cbind,split(val,Grp))

     res1 <-  as.data.frame(res,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     res1
     #       ASIN categories group Id salesrank
     #1 0827229534          2  Book  1    396585
     #2 0827529534          3 Book2  2    396587
```

Comment: I just did. Thanks again!